# How to reduce the width of table columns while using ellipsis text overflow styling?

Tags: html, css

I have a filled table which has column css styling which causes text that is overflowing to be `ellipsed`(shortened with ...).

The css styling for a `td` is the following:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
```

This works but it ellipses text way too soon. There are columns with unused empty space which have a bigger width than other columns that have text that is being ellipsed. When I specify the max-width to f.e. `15vw` this problem does not occur anymore but this causes other unwanted issues.

Is there another way to reduce the width of such table columns while using this ellipsis styling for the overflowing text?

Answer (score 1):

Use this like following

```css
table.table-ellipsis{
  width: 500px;
}
table.table-ellipsis td{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 25%;
  max-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

table.table-ellipsis td div{
  display:block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-ellipsis">
<tr> 
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Do</div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet   Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet </div> </td>
<td> <div> Lorem Ipsum Dol</div> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I am trying to keep `max-width: 0` in place because of unwanted issues that are caused through a max-width

Comment: `max-width:0` means that the content will never be rendered. `max-width:0` will force the div or span etc that its width will remain less than 0 always. and any item that has zero width will never be visible on screen